# Multiple Entries in SQL Database Instead of One Entry. (may be due to sessioning ?) 

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-4.0

I have used sessions in my web app.

and I sets up sessions on login with userid.

Sometimes when one user will post their problem using my web application,
than entry will be there with that perticular userid and another entry also be there with any random userid.

So, multiple entries will be there in same table in sql. (this happens randomly)
 (this happens - when 2-3 user trying to access same thing)

Sometimes it takes any other / random userid (may be previously logged in user id) and insert data with any userid.

Sometimes one user wants to see log of his activity
 so he able to see another users activities or all users activities or his own activities . this one happens randomly too.

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use session in your asp.net web app, please do not create session using below method.

```
Session["username"]=usernametxt.Text;//or assign it from dataset
```

but use class and functions for creating session, and use get and set method for that.

```
set { HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] = value; }
```

make sure

this is just as an example.

Comment: previously i have just used session["username"] instead of HttpContext.Current.Session["username"]. and now my problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using static class object for database transaction?  this happens due to statics objects.

Comment: no. i am using sql connection and sql command method on each button click event for sql database connection.

Comment: strange. are you using global connection  object ?

Comment: i am not using global connection object. but i am using " private static string userid" and  this userid in whole page.

Comment: that's what my earlier question was... static userid is causing the issue. please convert it to non static variable and check it.